# Google map API with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I want to design a html business card with a map icon (the icon will show a red pin of the address that's in the card). The map window will be very small (100 X 100 px), but upon click it will open google map with the address pinned. Is there a jQuery plugin that can easily achieve this, or would someone pls point me to the right direction?

Comment: Do you want the map to open in a lightbox, or blank window?

Comment: You wouldn't need jQuery to do that. You could simply open up a new window and send the user to Google Maps. The address can be passed as a GET-parameter.

Comment: both will be ok. it can even open in a div...as long as it can blow up to a bigger map upon click.

Comment: Thanks Chris, but in the small map icon i want to show actual location too.

Comment: Okay, but that could be done using the standard [Google Maps JavaScript-API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference). No need for jQuery there either.

Comment: Off the top of your head, do you know if that API gives me control to specify the map size?

Comment: The map size can be set either through the API, or by setting the `width` and `height` through CSS.

Comment: OK sounds good to me. It'll be my pleasure to mark it as answer if you can put it into an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Posted it as an answer.

Comment: Christofer, I would if I had the reputation to suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use jQuery to solve this.

I believe the easiest way to achieve this would be to open up a new window, and send the user to Google Maps. The address can be passed as a GET-parameter.

For the small map, you can use the standard [Google Maps JavaScript-API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), to put the marker on the map.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any jquery plugin for this. But what you describe should not be too difficult to achieve. I would do the following for this task.

```
$('#my_pin').click(function(){
  1. create a div for map, set the height and width for this div. 
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     you may want to add some event hanlder to this div so that it can be closed 

  2. create a google map options similar to 
     var opts = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(100,100),
       zoom: 5,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.mapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
  3. create your map object base on the newly created div and options
     var map = new google.maps.Map(div,opts )

  4. attach the new div to your body or whatever parent element
     $(div).appendTo($('body').get(0));



});
```